# When do I use 'use' and 'loader' in Webpack 2 module.rules?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I am upgrading my current project to **Webpack2**, which it was using **Webpack1** prior. I have looked into a couple tutorials about upgrading and in general, I do understand.

The issue I keep running into, though, is I'm not sure when to use 'use' and 'loader' in when specifying the module rules (loaders). At first, I thought `use` replaced `loader`. I understand this type of syntax:

```
module: {
  rules: [{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
          plugins: ...
        }
      },
      'sass-loader'
    ]
  }]
}
```

However, when I use the `ExtractTextPlugin` it doesn't seem to like when it's consdiered a `use`. I've tried this:

```
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
              fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
              loader: scssLoaders
            })
          }]
      },
```

with the `scssLoaders` being:

```
var scssLoaders = [
  {
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
      modules: true,
      importLoaders: '2',
      localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
    }
  },
  {
    loader: 'postcss-loader'
  },
  {
    loader: 'sass-loader',
    options: {
      outputStyle: 'expanded',
      sourceMap: true,
      sourceMapContents: true
    }
  }
];
```

I'll just stop here before I go off about other problems. Can someone please help explain what I am missing here? Feel free to ask for any other code you need to help!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As the [Webpack 2 migration tutorial](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/3/#moduleloaders-is-now-modulerules) states, the difference between both is, that if when we want an array of loaders, we have to use `use`, if it's just one loader, then we have to use `loader`:

```
module: {
   rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        loader: "babel-loader", // Do not use "use" here
        options: {
          // ...
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader!less-loader"
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          "less-loader"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Note: That using `loaders` as opposed to `loader` will still work but is now considered a legacy option https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#chaining-loaders

Comment: Great answer, thanks.  You have to love it when a tool already criticized for its complex configuration decides to make it even *harder* to configure by making you use two properties when you used to just be able to use one :(

Answer (score 15):

[`module.rules`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#module-rules) is meant for loaders. Specifying a rule as [`loader`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-loader) is just a shortcut for

```
use: [{loader}]
```

For plugins, use the [`plugins`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/) property in your configuration.