# Webpack - Cannot find module raw-loader

Tags: javascript, webpack

I need to load a JS file as a string so I can run some analysis on it. I am trying to use raw-loader with Webpack (2.2.0).

I get:  `Cannot find module 'raw-loader!../`

I've tried (yes, the path is correct):

```
let app = require('raw-loader!../../app.js').default;

let app = require('!!raw-loader!../../app.js').default;
```

I've even tried it without inline. Raw-loader doesn't get engaged, it just tried to load the JS file normally:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\app.js$/i,
        use: 'raw-loader',
        loader: 'raw-loader',
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

raw-loader is in my package.json for the project. It is present in my node modules. I've blown-away my node_modules and have reinstalled. I've looked at many solutions and nothing seems to point to a fix.

Comment: What version of raw-loader are you using?

Comment: I'm on 0.5.1 but I've also tried latest. I suspect there is something I'm missing in my config but I don't see it.

Answer (score 3):

You have an error in your regexp pattern.

You are using `\a` which matches the bell character (ASCII 7)

And `.` matches any character, you need to escape it.

Moreover, using both `use` and `loader` is misleading. You should use only one - see this answer:
[When do I use 'use' and 'loader' in Webpack 2 module.rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41750715/when-do-i-use-use-and-loader-in-webpack-2-module-rules#answer-43842709)

Try to use:

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /app\.js$/i,
        loader: 'raw-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: If I comment-out that rule, the inline version still doesn't work.

Comment: And did you try to use only loader from config file (with updated regex pattern of course)? Try to use config loader and import file like this - `let app = require('../../app.js').default;`

Comment: Plus I edited my answer for using `use` and `loader`.

Comment: Yes. I have tried every combination. It still can't find the raw-loder module.

Comment: Are you able to find the module, is it inside node_modules?

Comment: It is, yes. Also in package.json.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding resolve module extensions, resolve loaders

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveloader

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveloadermoduleextensions

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would update webpack. The version that you are using is, currently, 2 major versions behind the latest release. Maybe the error messages have been improved! Also, you can see more info about the error running `webpack --display-error-details`.

Comment: I would like to do that, but it's a huge project and I can't force this change on the rest of the team.